# VML rendering through Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, svg, vml

I want to create simple VML circle element through jquery. i have done this in SVG via jquery.

how can i create this VML circle element and need to attach this to some other container like "div"

sample VML code:

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"> 
<head> 
<style> v\:* { behavior: url(#default#VML); }</style > 
</head> 
<body> 
<v:rect  
style="width:50;  
height:50" 
fillcolor="green" 
strokecolor="black"/> 
</body> 
</html>
```

This will create the rectangle with green color.

i want to create this dynamically via jquery ?

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: Then put the markup in a jQuery selector, and then append that to your body.

Answer (score 0):

Well, why wont you just put the markup in a selector, and append it to the body?

```
$('<v:rect style="width:50; height:50" fillcolor="green" strokecolor="black"/>').appendTo('body')
```

Or append it to any container of your choice, that is.